# Matlab class set method call unexpectedly

Tags: matlab, class, oop

Matlab specifies [When [a] Set Method is Called](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-set-methods.html#buq4ipf)

I ran into odd results, so I conducted a series of tests on the following class:

```
% @cScenInsts/cScenInsts.m
%-------------------------

classdef cScenInsts < matlab.mixin.Copyable

properties
   TwinYrs = 5 % Default value
end % properties

methods

   function o = cScenInsts( TwinYrs_in ) % Constructor
      if exist('TwinYrs_in') && ~isempty( TwinYrs_in )
         o.TwinYrs = TwinYrs_in ;
      else
         o.TwinYrs = o.TwinYrs ;
      end % if
   end % function cScenInsts()

   function o = set.TwinYrs(o,TwinYrs_in)
      o.TwinYrs = TwinYrs_in;
      fprintf( '%s: Property TwinYrs = %g\n', mfilename, o.TwinYrs );
   end % function set.TwinYrs

end % methods

end % classdef
```

The `else` block is superfluous in this minimum working example, but in real life, I want it to invoke the set method, which sets the values of other dependent parameters.

Using the class definition above, I ran into mixed results in terms of whether they seemed to  follow the rules for when a set method is called.

UNEXPECTED behaviour in the following command: "Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition" shouldn't trigger set method, but it does.

```
>> o = cScenInsts;
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5
```

As well, "As an optimization, if MATLAB determines that a property value does not change as a result of an assignment referencing the property, MATLAB does not call the property set method".  It seems that if the property is on the LHS and RHS of the assignment and the value doesn't change, the set method isn't called.  This should apply above, as it is the else block that executes.  The above result shows that it doesn't apply, which is the effect I seek. My anxt is that I don't know how much confidence I can have in the reliability of this behaviour in all circumstances when it seems to contradict the optimization provision.

EXPECTED behaviour in the following command:

```
>> o = cScenInsts(3);
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 3
```

UNEXPECTED behaviour in the following command: "Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition" shouldn't trigger set method, but it does.

```
>> o = cScenInsts(5);
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5
```

EXPECTED behaviour in the following command:

```
>> o.TwinYrs = 3;
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 3
```

EXPECTED behaviour in the following command, since the property's `AbortSet` attribute not set to `true`

```
>> o.TwinYrs = 3;
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 3
```

UNEXPECTED behaviour in the following command: "Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition" shouldn't trigger set method, but it does.

```
>> o.TwinYrs = 5;
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5
```

AMBIGUOUS behaviour in the following command: On one hand, "[a]ssigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition" shouldn't trigger set method, but it does.  On the other hand, it can also be considered expected behaviour, since the property's `AbortSet` attribute not set to `true`

```
>> o.TwinYrs = 5;
   cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5
```

Can anyone please explain the unexpected and/or ambiguous results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from TMW:

> ...the statement:
>
> > "As an optimization, if MATLAB determines that a property value
> >     does not change as a result of an assignment referencing the
> >     property, MATLAB does not call the property set method."
>
> ...is plainly incorrect. This optimization does not exist -- the
>   only time MATLAB forgoes calling the setter due to an assignment not
>   changing the value is when "AbortSet" is set to true.<...snip...>
>
> As for the other unclear bullet points:
>
> > "Initializing default values in class definitions when loading the
> >     class"
>
> This refers to loading the class definition which happens when doing
>   “?” or when first constructing the class.  This is the
>   step that parses and compiles the class definition and sets the
>   DefaultValue property of the meta.property object accessible from
>   the meta.class object returned from ?.  This has nothing
>   to do with loading instances of a class from a MAT-File or loadobj.
>
> > "Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in
> >     the class definition"
>
> This bullet means that the set-function is not called when MATLAB
>   assigns a default value to a property when making a new instance of
>   a class.  This refers to the assignment of the default value during
>   property initialization. As we suspected, it does not refer to any
>   other assignment to a value that happens to be equal to the default
>   value.
>
> I will go ahead and submit the documentation update request...

Thank you all for having chimed in.

Answer (score 5):

I'll address each of the confusing bullet points you mention from [this list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-set-methods.html#buq4ipf) of cases when the property set method IS NOT called:

- > Initializing default values in class definitions when loading the class

  I believe this is specifically referring to creating a class object by loading it from a MAT-file (i.e. using the [`loadobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html) method). When loading the property values, they are simply copied without passing them to the set method.
- > Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition

  I believe this is specifically referring to when MATLAB *initially* creates the object and sets its default values. It does this without passing the values to any set methods first. To see this, you can add this line to the very beginning of your class constructor:

  ```
  disp(o);
  ```

  When you run your code, you'll see that a default object with the default property values is already created for you upon entering the constructor, before you've even done anything with the input arguments. These properties are set without invoking any set methods (as the bullet point states). Any *subsequent* changes to the property, like when you set them in your `if-else` statement, DOES still invoke the set method, as expected.

  You may notice then that your `else` statement is actually unnecessary in this case, since the defaults are already set. Removing the `else` statement will give you your expected behavior for:

  ```
  o = cScenInsts;
  ```

  As an additional aside, since you are subclassing the `matlab.mixin.Copyable` class (which has `handle` class behavior), you don't need to return an object from your set methods:

  ```
  function set.TwinYrs(o, TwinYrs_in)
    ...
  ```
- > As an optimization, if MATLAB determines that a property value does not change as a result of an assignment referencing the property, MATLAB does not call the property set method.

  This statement is a little unclear. As you already noted, leaving the [`AbortSet` attribute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/set-events-when-value-does-not-change.html) unset (i.e. it is set to `false` by default) means that the set method will still be called even when setting a property to the same value. The statement above seems to suggest that under some circumstances, even when the `AbortSet` attribute is `false`, MATLAB may still decide to forego calling the set method. If so, it's not clear what those conditions are under which that optimization is used.

Removing the `else` statement as I suggest above, here are the expected results for some of your examples above:

```
>> o = cScenInsts;  % Set method not invoked, default value used

>> o = cScenInsts(3);
cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 3  % Set method invoked, overriding default value

>> o = cScenInsts(5);
cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5  % Set method invoked, even though same as default value
                                  %   (since AbortSet is false)
>> o.TwinYrs = 5;
cScenInsts: Property TwinYrs = 5  % Set method invoked, even though same as current value
                                  %   (since AbortSet is false)
```

Comment: Thanks, gnovice. The phrase "Assigning a property to its default value that is specified in the class definition" needs revising to reflect your explanation. TMW has already seen this thread, so they may do this. You said the `else` block is unneeded, but I want it to invoke the set method, which in real life has many more side effects than shown here. You also said that returning `matlab.mixin.Copyable` objects is unnecessary, but I hope it doesn't hurt, as I want as little difference from the more "normal" classes as possible (not an expert in by-val/by-ref under the hood).

Comment: @user36800: Yeah, that statement could be written clearer, since I'm pretty sure they mean to say what I explained above. The `else` block is only unnecessary for your simplified example. I don't *think* there's any harm in returning the handle object. I think it's just not required.

Comment: Regarding "If Matlab determines that a property value does not change as a result of an assignment referencing the property, Matlab does not call the property set method", I agree that the set method might be not called even if `AbortSet` is `false`.

Comment: From the wording, it seems that this applies if the RHS contains the property itself. This torpedoes the side-effects that results from the else block code in real life. That's why I need to suss out *exactly* when set methods aren't called. If the "optimization" caveat applies, I need another way. Tests show that it doesn't apply, which contradicts the wording. I can't proceed with confidence.

Comment: Note that if `TwinYrs` is 5 and you do `TwinYrs = 5`, MATLAB is not going to see that the value will not change. Doing so would require doing a deep comparison, which is likely more expensive (generally) than just making the assignment. Where it is easy for MATLAB to see that the value is identical is when the new matrix shares data with the matrix that is already there. Example: `tmp=TwinYrs; TwinYrs=tmp;`.

Comment: And consequently I can see that "Assigning a property to its default value" is the same issue: it's not going to do a deep comparison to see if the value is identical to the default value. To me it is clearly referring to the initial assignment of the default value in the definition.

Comment: When weighing the cost of doing assignment versus deep comparison, it's worthwhile keeping in mind that the former means triggering the set method, which can have much more costlier side effects. I wouldn't necessarily conclude that they forgo deep comparison, though they might. Having said that, it seems that the set method is triggered most of the time, and many of the conditions for skipping it need to be more accurately described. The one that still gets me is the "optmization" proviso, which torpedoes my else-block, which I want in order to guarantee the side effects of the set method.

Comment: @user36800: Why don't you make a separate private method that you call from both the set method and the constructor, as needed? You can also overload `subsasgn`, which is always called for `obj.prop=value` outside of class methods (it's never invoked from within class methods).

Comment: I don't think the set method is supposed to have side effects. It's there to check for valid values, and maybe adjust other dependent properties. I wouldn't want to use it to e.g. write data to a file or trigger expensive computations. Use custom class methods for that.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of making a private method called by both the constructor and set method.  But if the code can be streamlined based on actual (but guaranteed) behaviour of set methods, I would prefer that.  The guarantee is the hard part, because even if I empirically determine the behaviour, and it contradicts the documentation, I don't know what circumstances are needed to guarantee the behaviour.